# how to set CommandLine Blender default version?

Tags: command-line

I type blender in the command line tools, then 3.3 start, but i want to use blender 3.4 actually, so how can i specify the start blender version?

Answer (score 1):

Under <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>System</kbd> > <kbd>Operating System Settings</kbd> click <kbd>Make Default</kbd>. The next time you start Blender it will use this version.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I set 3.4 to enviroment path works, may helps who want

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.